# I want to attached an Angular2 Component to a newly added DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, angular, typescript

I want to bind an Angular2 Component to a newly added dom.

What happen is: `<my-app>` tag is not updated with `<h1>My First Angular App</h1>`. With the code below, having a small DOM, `my-app` tag contains `<h1>My First Angular App</h1>`, but with huge DOM, it didn't, I only see `my-app` tag.

Here is my code:

## Component.TS

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<h1>My First Angular App</h1>"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

## Main.TS

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
//APPModule not included on this post, same as the quickstart
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";


interface MyWindow extends Window {
    displayApp(): void;
}

declare var window: MyWindow;

window.displayApp = function displayApp() {
    const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
    platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

## Some Javascript Code

```
//adding the selection component dom. 
document.getElementById('main-content').appendChild(document.createElement('my-app'));
//do ajax call then on success
window.displayApp();
```

Having a full angular approach is not an option here because there are existing ui component based on other technology, and we are exploring angular on other components.

Comment: What's the problem? Any error message? How does the resulting DOM look like? What do you mean by "full angular approach"?

Comment: It just didn't bind.. I only have <my-app></app>  which doesn't contain <h1>My First Angular App</h1>. But I did check if displayApp is executed using console.log and it is executed.

Comment: I don't get from your question what "On small DOM it works but on huge DOM with json request it doesn't." means.

Comment: The code works when you have a small DOM (small html) like just having a empty body but once you have a huge dom (lot's of div, children, etc.), it doesn't work.